# A word for a complex problem that needs to be approached form different angles at the same time

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

For example:

There is a problem A.
To solve A x, y and z are needed.
But you can't have x without y, the lack of y is problematic for z, without which x is impossible.

Looking for a word that would describe this and would be more colorful than 'complex'.

Thank you!

Comment: I would like to suggest *intricate* or *entangled*.

Answer (score 4):

*Multifaceted*. Literally, "having many sides". Figuratively, having many different aspects or features.

Answer (score 3):

That's an ***intricate*** problem:

> OED - interwinding in a complicated manner.
>
> M-W - having many complexly interrelating parts or elements.

Another good word is ***convoluted***.

Answer (score 1):

A [Gordian knot](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Gordian+knot)

> n.
>   1. An exceedingly complicated problem or deadlock.

A deadlock being when A can't move / be solved before B, and B can't move before A.

Comment: Though the figurative description of the problem suggests that a similarly simple and straightforward solution must exist as in the original.

Comment: +1 but ironically, the Alexandrian solution did not involve approaching from different angles, just one.

Comment: @bib, quite an acute angle at that.

Comment: @JonHanna Sharp as always.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider:

```
**interdependent** *adjective* :  2. reciprocal <interrelation> 
2a :  determined or conditioned by another
```

Although I wouldn't consider the *problem* interdependent, the relatinoships are interdependent, which I think implies a complex problem and adds the description you seek.

*from "inter" and "dependent;" m-w.com*